# Gigabyte Z97 D3H won't post after shutdown, fixed by RAM reconfiguration every time

Tags: memory, motherboard, post

My Gigabyte GA-Z97-D3H motherboard has recently developed new problem. I works OK as long as I don't shut down computer but only put it to sleep. If I shut it down, the next time when I turn it on, it won't post, instead it's making slow ticking sound (1 every 2 seconds or so) by motherboard speaker without any progress. This is solved by reconfiguring the RAM, such as swapping two sticks of it, or removing two out of four, or adding 2 back if they were removed before. Then it posts as usual and works for days till the next shutdown.
The fact that changing RAM "fixes" this problem probably means that it's not anything with the faulty hardware, right? then what could it be?

Comment: Sounds like a motherboard problem

Comment: I'd start by replacing any MB battery. Especially if configs are being lost.

Comment: For the record - the problem was fixed by re-applying the same BIOS.
I wonder it the BIOS does not have control sum or something, self-checked on boot, that would allow detection if it got changed somehow.